# What window should I grow my San Pedro Cactus?

Tags: indoors, succulents, cactus, sunlight

I have a baby San Pedro cactus and I'm wondering if I can grow it indoors in a west facing window. I live in the UK and the cactus seems healthy, it's only about 5-6 inches tall.

Comment: Yes, but South is better. More sun.

Comment: Your cactus will enter dormancy anyway during the British autumn and winter. Just do not put it close up to a window in a centrally heated room at full blast since the change of temperatures and the cold from the window once the c/h goes off at night will surely kill it. A south facing kitchen would be a better choice but if that isn't available, a few hours a day under a simple grow light might help it a little if positioned away from a cold window.